# How can I query and order nodes with multiple date field values within a specific range?

Tags: 7, entities, database

I'm trying to get nodes that have date fields (multiple instances in some cases) and display them sorted ascending by start time for a given date. For illustrative purposes, here are some events and their date field values (start time).

**Event A**

- 4/2/17 8:00AM
- 4/3/17 2:00PM

**Event B**

- 4/3/17 11:00AM
- 4/3/17 5:00PM

**Event C**

- 4/3/17 6:00PM

**Event D**

- 4/4/17 4:00AM

I'm using EntityFieldQuery to gather the events with dates on 4/3/17 and order them using this code;

```
$query
->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
->entityCondition('bundle', 'event')
->propertyCondition('status', 1)
->fieldCondition('field_datetime', 'value', array('2017-04-03/T00:00:00', '2017-04-04/T00:00:00'), 'BETWEEN')
->fieldOrderBy('field_datetime', 'value', 'ASC');
```

I get the nodes ordered like this;

A, B, C

but I want them ordered like this;

B, A, C

I guess the fieldOrderBy method is looking at all the date field values and ordering that way, which includes dates other than my target (4/3/17).

Anyone know how to accomplish this (with EntityFieldQuery or without)?

Answer (score 0):

Are the date/time values stored as a varchar in your database? If I'm not mistaken, in that case the ordering is performed by comparing the String values (which is inline with the outcome of your example, i.e., A:2, B:5, C:6).

You could alter your query, using [hook_query_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7.x), and cast/convert the datatype to datetime (not sure whether every database supports this).

The easiest solution would be to sort the query result afterwards, using the [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function and in your comparison function you can use PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object or the [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to compare the values.